# How to store a JSON response file larger than 3 MB or more increase in an android SQLite DB at Android App installation time or sync

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to make an *Android app* work both online or offline.

How would I store a JSON response with a file size of more than 3 MB or a greater increase in an *Android* SQLite DB at an *Android app* installation with time or sync?

1. Handle JSON response, but some partial data storing in SQLite database ?
2. How to store the complete database or more than 3 MB to SQLite at app installation time?

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you try something which return you an error? Can you show us your code? Please see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then edit your question.

Comment: @ Manoj Kumar Provide the code that what you tried?